# MS Access Tab Control: Wrong focus

Tags: ms-access, tabcontrol

I have a tab control with different pages. When starting up the form with this tab control the tabs get lost and the inner page gets all the screen focus. The tab control is used for navigation so the user will get lost this way.

Is there any way to let the tabs be visible on the screen without just resizing the screen to be smaller?

**Desired result:**

```
+--------------------+
| Tab1 | Tab2 | Tab3 |
+--------------------+
| Name: ______       |
```

**Actual screen:**

```
                        ^
+--------------------+ |_|
| Name: ______       | | |
```

Comment: Are you setting the focus in code? Have you ordered the tab pages appropriately? Have you adjusted the tab order so that the tab is in the right place in comparison to the other controls on the form? Have you set the tab order for the controls on each tab?

Comment: Yes, been there, done that. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Frankly, I don't even understand the question at all. I was hoping that in answering some of my questions you would reveal enough that I could understand it, but since you're not going to, I'll just ignore this one until such time as you make an effort to explain what your problem is that doesn't require a lot of guessing.

Comment: I still don't understand the question, but have you set the width of your tabs to something that is too wide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reducing the size of the tab control works (as you discovered yourself), however there is an alternative workaround:

1. Add a command button and align it with the top left corner of the tab control
2. Set its Tab Stop property to No (in the 'Other' tab of the command button property sheet)
3. Send To Back to put the command button behind the tab control
4. In the Form's `OnOpen` or `OnLoad` event, call the `.SetFocus` method on the command button
5. Use `SendKeys` (I know, I know...) to tab to the Tab Control

Sample code:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.HiddenCommandButton.SetFocus
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
End Sub
```

Explanation of the above steps:

1. This allows you to dictate to Access where it should line up the form on screen.
2. Setting the Tab Stop to No for the command button prevents users from accidentally tabbing to it and causing confusion.
3. Sending the button to the back hides it from the user and prevents it from interfering with any mouse clicking.
4. Setting focus to the command button at form start up is necessary since we turned off the Tab Stop property in step 2.
5. Using SendKeys (always a last resort, and for good reason) to simulate a tab press provides "keyboard focus" to the Tab Control (as long as the tab control is the first control in the tab order for whatever section of the form the control is a part of).

**Miscellaneous Notes**:  At the asker's request I am including a couple of comments as part of the answer itself:

> *@mwolfe*: One final note on SendKeys...it blows up under UAC in
>   Vista/Win7. If you can live without
>   the keyboard focus, I'd say leave
>   SendKeys out entirely. If you need it
>   you'll either want to add error
>   handling to ignore the error (if you
>   don't mind some of your users losing
>   keyboard focus functionality) or
>   bypass SendKeys and use the WinAPI
>   directly. Karl Peterson offers a
>   turnkey solution here:
>   [vb.mvps.org/samples/SendInput](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/SendInput) I have
>   never used it so can't comment on its
>   reliability, but Karl is a Microsoft
>   MVP so he's get some credibility.
>
> *@Roman Glass*:  mwolfe02 I trust you in that this method will work, but the
>   focus is crucial for me AND some users
>   are working under Windows 7. I will
>   drop this issue for the moment to find
>   out about the user reactions.
>   Nevertheless I think your solution
>   deserves a solved. In the end I have
>   to talk with the WinAPI. Maybe you can
>   edit your answer to include this
>   comment directly. Thanks!

For those who may find this answer in the future, please take note that Step 5 above is only necessary if you need the tab control to receive keyboard focus (a critical requirement for the original asker).  If you can live without it, I would suggest that you do.

**UPDATE**:  As David Fenton points out in the comments, you can use `Ctl` + `Tab`/`Ctl` + `Shift` + `Tab` to move back and forth between the tabs.  This is consistent with most tabbed interfaces (eg, browsers) and eliminates the need to use `SendKeys`.

Comment: But this will set the focus on the button and not inside of the form. And with focus I mean the keyboard focus which is important, too. Take this with a grain of salt because I did not test this.

Comment: Good point on the keyboard focus.  I knew this as a limitation of my solution when I posted it, but could not think of any way around it.  I cringed just writing SendKeys since it's generally evil.  In this case, however, I felt it was a necessary evil.

Comment: By the way, I tested the steps above and confirmed that they work.

Comment: I forgot to explicitly mention it in my previous comments, but I updated my answer to address your concerns about the keyboard focus.

Comment: One final note on SendKeys...it blows up under UAC in Vista/Win7.  If you can live without the keyboard focus, I'd say leave SendKeys out entirely.  If you need it you'll either want to add error handling to ignore the error (if you don't mind *some* of your users losing keyboard focus functionality) or bypass SendKeys and use the WinAPI directly.  Karl Peterson offers a turnkey solution here: http://vb.mvps.org/samples/SendInput/  I have never used it so can't comment on its reliability, but Karl is a Microsoft MVP so he's get some credibility.

Comment: SendKeys is never necessary. Any time you paint yourself into a corner where it's the only option, it's an indication that you made a mistake a long time before you got to the SendKeys.

Comment: Agreed.  But in this case it's the MS Access team that painted us into this corner when they chose not to implement a .SetFocus method for a Tab Control.  If you know of another way to set the focus to the tabs of a tab control programmatically, I'm all ears.

Comment: I still have never understood your explanation of the problem, so my guess would be that you probably don't need to setfocus to the tab control. In any event, it's perfectly possible with Me!ctlTab.Pages(N).SetFocus (where N is the index of the tab page you want to set focus to), or with Me!pgeTabPageName.SetFocus.

Comment: That sets focus to the first control on Me!ctlTab.Pages(N).SetFocus, not the tab control itself.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding the OP's question, but I believe he wants the form to open with the focus on the tab control itself.  One reason you might want to do this is so that when users open the form, they can use the left and right arrow keys to move among the pages of the tab control.

Comment: mwolfe02 I trust you in that this method will work, but the focus is crucial for me AND some users are working under Windows 7. I will drop this issue for the moment to find out about the user reactions. Nevertheless I think your solution deserves a solved. In the end I have to talk with the WinAPI. Maybe you can edit your answer to include this comment directly. Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that Ctrl-Tab moves between the tabs? It's also consistent with all the tabbed browsers (and existed long before web browsers had tabs).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I know I've only played with the Tab control once or twice - but never had a problem with it showing up on the form when the form is executed/loaded.  Granted, I've never had it in any place except the Detail section of the form, but I'd say check to see if the beast has somehow gotten it's Enabled or Visible property (if applicable) set to No.  Of course, I could be wrong - it happens, and I am eager to learn something new when it happens.  :)

Comment: If it were something with the visibility property I suppose that it wouldn't show up at all. In the end it was just that MS Access was trying to figure out how to place the form into the window. Maybe there should be a property to place something like an anchor on top of the tab control. Hope we both learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I understand the question, but in a comment, you say that Access doesn't allow you to set focus to a tab control, but you can set focus to the tab page:

```
  Me!ctlTab.Pages(N).SetFocus
```

...where N is the index of the tab page you want to set focus to), or with:

```
  Me!pgeTabPageName.SetFocus
```

Both of these work to set focus to the tab page.

You say you want to set focus to the tab control, but I can't figure out why you'd want to do that. The tab control itself has no elements that can get focus -- only the members of its Pages collection do.

Again, I would suggest that you've painted yourself into a corner for some other reason and there's no solution. Therefore, you have to figure out how to avoid getting into that insoluble problem. I simply don't understand your explanation of the problem well enough to be able to offer a solution, but I doubt there's no way to resolve the issue through a different approach.

Comment: As mwolfe02 understood correctly the problem occurs when the page is larger than the actual screen estate. If this situation occurs, then the tabbed pane becomes invisible for the user. You have to scroll up to see that you are inside of a tab control. What you really want is that the focus of the top of this page should never be lost to guarantee visibility of basic navigation. The corner you mentioned is that this Access Application has to work under different screen resolutions.

Comment: Well, pardon me for not understanding your very unclear question. I don't know why you've downvoted the answer -- I said quite clearly it's not the answer you want. Frankly, I have a hard time understand why you'd want a tab control larger than the screen. It sounds like an extremely user-hostile design to me. That MS hasn't accounted for it (and it therefore doesn't work) is not something I think I'm going to get too bent out of shape about, as the answer it so use a tab control in a much more reasonable manner.

Comment: Is down voting considered rude on stackoverflow? Then I am sorry. I just thought of it as sorting out questions that don't really fit. Yes, my question was quite unclear, so sorry for that, again, I tried to change that. What I really need would be a floating design which fit the different screen resolutions dynamically. Actually I started to use less screen estate to make it fit the worst case. This was downright rejected by my user base. So maybe we have different experiences with users. Why shouldn't MS think about different resolutions?

Comment: A2007/2010 add some capability for doing this, by creating grouped control layouts. I haven't used it, but I know it exists. I don't know how successful it is. The Access Developer's Handbook had code to do this for you, but it was not entirely successful. There's also this: http://www.peterssoftware.com/ss.htm , which has been around quite a long time and I know people have mentioned using it. I can't say one way or the other.

Comment: As to downvoting, I try to downvote only WRONG answers, not ones that are not necessarily addressing the question directly. The reason for that is because it is often the case that related issues really need to be discussed in order to home in on the correct answer, usually because the question itself needs refinement that often doesn't come until after some answers have been registered.